# ListView top highlight on scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

The border displays a default color (that's orange on my Nexus S) while scrolling a ListView to the limit. How to change that color?

I really don't know how to explain it. Just look at this picture:

[image: android list view top highlight on scrolling]

So, how to change the highlight color when the ListView scrolling to the border? using themes or styles

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Comment: set android:cacheColorHine="#676767" in list view

Comment: it's not android:cacheColorHine problem. android:cacheColorHine is already transparent. The problem is in this orange line, which is APPEAR ONLY WHEN YOU SCROLL at the end of the list view. See, you are already on the end (or start) of the list view and you continue scrolling bottom (or up). but its not scrolling cos we are already at the end (or at the top) of the list, and this orange line appear

Comment: People I think this highlight only in Nexus S model

Comment: Yes, I did. Its in @louiscoquio's post

Comment: @Bhuro, the link in your answer has been moved to http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html . Hope this helps people.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution is to use `setOverscrollFooter(null)` and `setOverscrollHeader(null)`.
The documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) !

You can also set it directly in the XML :

```
<ListView android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Or specify the footer and the header :

```
<ListView 
  android:overscrollHeader="@null" 
  android:overscrollFooter="@null" />
```

N.B. : There is also a property `fadingEdge` that may interest you.

"Overscroll" methodes are supported starting API level 9

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, I didn't see it because of its since API Level 9

Comment: I tried its not working nothing changes i can still see the blue api 17

Comment: Worked for me. I'm on API 21.

Comment: Of course, other carriers (non-nexus) love to override this kind of thing.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found the solution.

1. `setOverscrollFooter(null)` and `setOverscrollHeader(null)` does not work. At least on 2.3.*. Setting attributes from *.xml doesn't help too.
2. `setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)` causes glitchy scrolling. At least on 2.3.*.

The only solution that really works involves the use of Java Reflection.
It works even with ugly custom Samsung listviews with bounce overscroll effect.
Here is a snippet:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    //onOverScrolled method must be overrided, or we will see the background of the listview when overscroll fast.
}

private void removeOverscrollEffect() {
    try {
        Class<?> superClass = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();

        Field field = superClass.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object edgeGlowTop = field.get(this);
        if (edgeGlowTop != null) {
            Class<? extends Object> edgeClass = edgeGlowTop.getClass();
            Field edgeDrawable = edgeClass.getDeclaredField("mEdge");
            edgeDrawable.setAccessible(true);
            edgeDrawable.set(edgeGlowTop, new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            Field glowDrawable = edgeClass.getDeclaredField("mGlow");
            glowDrawable.setAccessible(true);
            glowDrawable.set(edgeGlowTop, new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            field.set(this, edgeGlowTop);
        }

        Field fieldBottom = superClass.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
        fieldBottom.setAccessible(true);
        Object edgeGlowBottom = fieldBottom.get(this);
        if (edgeGlowBottom != null) {
            Class<? extends Object> edgeClassBottom = edgeGlowBottom.getClass();
            Field edgeDrawableBottom = edgeClassBottom.getDeclaredField("mEdge");
            edgeDrawableBottom.setAccessible(true);
            edgeDrawableBottom.set(edgeGlowBottom, new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            Field glowDrawableBottom = edgeClassBottom.getDeclaredField("mGlow");
            glowDrawableBottom.setAccessible(true);
            glowDrawableBottom.set(edgeGlowBottom, new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            fieldBottom.set(this, edgeGlowBottom);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. This is great answer. How could this has not been noticed yet. Really you are genius. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This stopped working in Lollipop. See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31786095/2603965

Comment: Not worked for me. I took a class extending ListView and override  onOverScrolled(), then called removeOverScrollEffect() from onOverScrolled(). But with no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice article on [ListView Backgrounds Optimization](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html).

> To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. You can do this from code (see setCacheColorHint(int)) or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the **`transparent color #00000000`**. The following screenshot shows a list with `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Comment: Hi, The question is not about cacheColor. It is about the changing colour for overScrollMode effect.

Answer (score 3):

Use it in XML file--

```
<ListView ---
     android:fadingEdge="none"
   ---</ListView>
```

**EDITED:**

Using fading edges may introduce noticeable performance degradations and should be used only when required by the application's visual design. To request fading edges with API level 14 and above, use the **android:requiresFadingEdge** attribute instead.

Check this API [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge)

Comment: thank you!!!, the fadingEdge is not work well with if i have padding and clipToPadding false

Comment: @Shawn Thye: my answer was very old as some new API has been updated. Check my edited answer.

Comment: haha, your are right, but I only need to disable it on low api device

Answer (score 2):

I used kord's answer until it stopped working in Lollipop, so I changed into this:

```
try {
    Class<?> superClass = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();

    Field field = superClass.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(this, new NoEdgeEffect(getContext()));

    Field fieldBottom = superClass.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
    fieldBottom.setAccessible(true);
    fieldBottom.set(this, new NoEdgeEffect(getContext()));
} catch (Exception e) {
}

class NoEdgeEffect extends EdgeEffect
{
    public NoEdgeEffect(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Do nothing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is just to hide overScroll effect. For doing that, you can use only 1 line: android:overScrollMode="never"

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:listSelector="#002234".

In above value can be any color code that you can find on internet easily.

Comment: no, it's not that. It changes color when you press on list view, but not color that appears when you rich end of the list view

Comment: reach at the end means? what you want exactly i didnot get you i think ?

Comment: Do you see this orange line? It APPEARS ONLY WHEN YOU SCROLL at the end of the list view. See, you are already on the end (or start) of the list view and you continue scrolling bottom (or up). but its not scrolling cos we are already at the end (or at the top) of the list, and this orange line appear

Comment: then try to use android:cacheColorHint="#00000000".Tell me if it is working.This is for other purpose but it may work.just try it.

Comment: yes, I set it before (there was black cover with background on scroll), and it hide problem with background, but not this orange line

Comment: @Pleerock Have you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @AndroEmbedded the solution is in the louiscoquio answer

Comment: this will change the List Item background color on its selection, not the overscroll highlight color of the list view.