# Android - How to change color of an ScrollView/ListView Overscroll?(see Desc. for example)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the color of over scroll in scrollview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062616/changing-the-color-of-over-scroll-in-scrollview-in-android)

I wanted to ask, if somebody knows how to change the color this "overscroll"?
I know you can get rid of it by calling `setOverscrollmode="never"`. But how do you cahnge its color?

Here the Picture, so you know what I mean:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think this SO Post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777803/listview-top-highlight-on-scrolling
Except instead of setting them to `@null` give them a color or reference...

Comment: It is not working for me. I'm developing an app for ICS, and the default holo blue color appears even if I set overscroll header and footer. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following attributes in your xml `ListView`

```
 android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/the_header"
 android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/the_footer"
```

Or you can do it programmatically, too:

```
SetOverscrollHeader(R.drawable.the_header);
setOverscrollFooter(R.drawable.the_footer);
```

These methods and attributes are only available since API 9; they won't work on the previous versions.

Comment: i used these method but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ListView
      ...
      android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/header"
      android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/footer"/>
```

Comment: @Chinaski should i add any transparent image for this