# Changing color of OverScroll Android

Tags: android, drawable

Here's an explanation on changing the color using drawables:

[Android - How to change color of an ScrollView/ListView Overscroll?(see Desc. for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604624/android-how-to-change-color-of-an-scrollview-listview-overscrollsee-desc-fo)

My question is: What does the drawable xml look like to change the color? Do I need to do something like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   "put something here"
</color>
```

Comment: You want to see what color does this drawable correspond to ?

Answer (score -1):

This should help answer your question:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

You can create a colors.xml file in your res/values directory and create color resources.

```
<resources>
    <color name="Red">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: If the file goes in res/values, why is the question I posted referring to a file in drawables?