# How to get rid of the overscroll glow

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with overscroll mode on - (I need it on)

And there is a blue overscroll glow everytime I overscroll

how do I get rid of the overscroll glow ?

EDIT:

I am using a custom listview that streches the overscroll drawable (picture) - the way it should be
however, along with the picture there is a glowing effect which i want to get rid of

see the blue thing above the image?

the image IS the overScrollDrawable - but i want the same thing - without the glow

[image]

Comment: can you please be more clear with your problem.

Comment: Check this. I hope you get your answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604624/android-how-to-change-color-of-an-scrollview-listview-overscrollsee-desc-fo

Comment: do you want to change the color ...or totally remove it???

Comment: @Jlazar89 totally remove it

Comment: @LenaBru Check out my answer. Its just simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView top highlight on scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777803/listview-top-highlight-on-scrolling)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: If you use a Pull to Refresh Library will this Conflict with that?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set your `ListView` property `fadeEdge` to none in your layout xml file and you will not get the shadow blue on OVERSCROLL.

`android:fadingEdge="none"`

**EDIT:**

this is now deprecated, you can use `android:overScrollMode="never"` instead.

Comment: This has been deprecated in API level 14.

Answer (score -2):

In the `ListView` you can set the drawable when overscrolling on top or bottom. This is usually set to a white/transparent drawable that is animated with fadeIn and fadeOut. To set the glowing to something fully transparent you can write:

```
ListView listView = ...;
listView.setOverscrollFooter(new ColorDrawable(0));
listView.setOverscrollHeader(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

This keeps the overscroll itself active, so that you can react on overscrolling events, but the glowing should be gone.

Comment: I have a different drawable for the overscroll drawable...
is it possible to make it work with it?

Comment: if you have a different drawble to apply ...then you must check this [project](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride)

Comment: Does nothing. Tested with API 19.