# Disable overscroll on 2.3.5? Or change colour?

Tags: android

So apparently overScroll options don't actually exist in 2.3.5-2.3.7 because of some silly reasons.

```
.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
```

Does a fine job at disabling it, but it breaks my listview in the sense that it no longer enables flinging at all.

Is there a library or some overriding I can do to change the colour of the overscroll or perhaps even disable it properly?

Setting the overscroll mode to never in the XML does not work either..

The issue does not occur on 4.1, 2.3.3, 4.2, 3.x, or 4.01

Comment: Perhaps post some more information about your `ListView` implementation or the device you are using, because setting the mode should not affect flinging in the way you describe (I've tested and handful of devices here from 2.3.5 to 4.2).  Although there was a bug in 2.3.x where setting this would cause a list to snap up once it hit the bottom when you fling it, but the flinging portion should work.  Also, this bug did not exist in later versions.

Comment: Its just a normal listview nothing different about it. 2.3.5-2.3.7 has overscroll issues on the GS2 because of the rubber banding lawsuit with apple. They disabled the overscroll effect but indadvertedly disabled other overscroll options.

Comment: Check this answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777803/listview-top-highlight-on-scrolling/17569996#17569996

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to add android:scrollbars="none",

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

    </ListView>
```